# How to check a feature installed on an msi from another product

Tags: windows-installer

If it is same product, we can check with upgrade code.
But my case is bit different.
I have an msi where,if the particular feature is installed then my 2nd msi should uninstall the 1st msi that particular feature only and install its features.
Note: Just we have upgrade code of 1st msi.

Please suggest how to do this.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are doing. There might be better deployment designs. For example merge modules or similar. Or side-by-side deployment. There are many options that might not be obvious at first.

Comment: I should also point out that you might have difficulties with elevated rights in locked down environments with this approach, as you can not run two InstallExecuteSequence's at once. Hence you must run immediate mode custom action and they are not elevated.

Comment: You might want to do this from your `setup.exe` launcher is what I forgot to add. What MSI tool are you using? Then you can inspect the system and run each MSI in sequence. Document requirement for large scale deployment scenarios and provide a batch file, powershell-script or vbscript to do the work?

Answer (score 1):

> The below uses [VBScript and COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/automation-interface-reference). You can also do the same via [Win32
>   functions (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/installer-function-reference). I guess COM is essentially a wrapper on top of the real Win32 functions.

---

Hmm, that sounds like an odd design, but you can get features and their state easily:

```vb
Set i = Wscript.CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
state = i.FeatureState("{PRODUCT-CODE-GUID-HERE}", "FeatureName")
MsgBox state
```

**Feature State: `3`** is normal local installation. The rest: [What does the feature state number mean?](https://github.com/metoo10987/Win7SDK/blob/b172eb9f7fd559a68636ed3f7e1a30f3000c6707/sample/Win7SDK%20Samples/Samples/sysmgmt/msi/scripts/WiLstPrd.vbs#L8) ([sample use](https://github.com/metoo10987/Win7SDK/blob/b172eb9f7fd559a68636ed3f7e1a30f3000c6707/sample/Win7SDK%20Samples/Samples/sysmgmt/msi/scripts/WiLstPrd.vbs#L110)).

If you need to obtain the product code from the upgrade code:

```vb
Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Set upgrades = installer.RelatedProducts("{UPGRADE-CODE-GUID-HERE}")

For Each u In upgrades
   MsgBox u, vbOKOnly, "Product Code: "
Next
```

Note that many products can share the same upgrade code.

---

Snippet to uninstall a feature. [Use Orca to find real feature name](https://superuser.com/a/785825/11906):

```vb
Set i = Wscript.CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
config = i.ConfigureFeature ("{PRODUCT-CODE-GUID-HERE}", "FeatureName", 2)
```

To install a feature, the value should be **`3`** ([`msiInstallStateLocal`](https://github.com/metoo10987/Win7SDK/blob/b172eb9f7fd559a68636ed3f7e1a30f3000c6707/sample/Win7SDK%20Samples/Samples/sysmgmt/msi/scripts/WiLstPrd.vbs#L8)), to uninstall **`2`** ([`msiInstallStateAbsent`](https://github.com/metoo10987/Win7SDK/blob/b172eb9f7fd559a68636ed3f7e1a30f3000c6707/sample/Win7SDK%20Samples/Samples/sysmgmt/msi/scripts/WiLstPrd.vbs#L8)).

---

***Links***:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/installer-featurestate